# Animate background-size: zoom to background-size: 110%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to CSS animate a background from the size `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: 120%` on hover. I cannot have the background start at 100% as it begins to repeat itself vertically on different devices/monitors. However, the `transition:.5s;`stops any type of animation when this is the case. Any workaround for this?

Code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="desktop-signs">
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="col-md-4 block-service" id="block-illustration">
      <h2>ILLUSTRATION &amp; ANIMATION</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="col-md-4 block-service" id="block-website">
      <h2>WEBSITE DEVELOPMENT</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="col-md-4 block-service" id="block-game">
      <h2>GAME &amp; APP DEVELOPMENT</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.__hero-container #services .block-service {
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url('../images/blockillustration.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 1;

  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
}

.__hero-container #services .block-service:hover {
  background-size: 110%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Add the transition to the :hover as well, perhaps?

Comment: `background-repeat: no-repeat` and `background-size: 100%` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the transition to the :hover element doesn't work either :(
And I can't use `background-repeat: no-repeat` because I get black borders where the image doesn't repeat. It's div changes size dynamically based off the browser width. Using Bootstrap!

Comment: Adding the transition to the :hover selector should work, but background-cover isn't a transition-able property.

Comment: Apparently using cover doesn't work with transition. Turnip posted a brilliant work-around using the :before pseudo elements!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have realised you can not animate from `cover` to any other value.

You could fake the effect with a scaled pseudo element:

```css
.block-service {
  height: 800px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block-service:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/400x400');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block-service:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-signs">
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="col-md-4 block-service" id="block-illustration">
      <h2>ILLUSTRATION &amp; ANIMATION</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="col-md-4 block-service" id="block-website">
      <h2>WEBSITE DEVELOPMENT</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="col-md-4 block-service" id="block-game">
      <h2>GAME &amp; APP DEVELOPMENT</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're the most genius Turnip I know. This worked perfectly. You're a god!

Comment: It is a little known fact that the turnip is the most intelligent of all root vegetables.

Comment: I will eat more Turnips!